# Objective-c How to release memory Uigraphicsbeginimagecontextwithoptions

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, release

This is my code using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` merge image

```
-(UIImage*)mergeHorizontal:(UIImage*)p1 p2:(UIImage*)p2{
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(p1.size.width + p2.size.width, p1.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 1.0);

[p1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,p1.size.width, size.height)];
[p2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(p1.size.width,0,p2.size.width, size.height)];

UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return finalImage;
}
```

But memory don't release when i call `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()`.

I try using `@autoreleasepool` but it not release memory and if i using many my method `mergeHorizontal` my app is memory leak.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBQhv.png]
Thank you if you have any answer!.

Comment: Try to replace UIGraphicsBeginImageContext   with UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions ,

Comment: There is no memory leak in the code you posted. Use Instruments and find your actually memory problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cut many image and edit frame with only UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions.